# How to prevent requesting duplicate data in RESTKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

I'm new to `RESTKit`, I have been developing iOS Client for a Restful service. we use `since_id` or something like that to make sure that we don't request for a same data over and over again. 
But in `RESTKit`, I haven't found any way to achieve such purpose.

Is there any completed open-source Restful service client that use `RESTKit`?

Comment: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1079

Comment: Not a error like duplicating. Just how to make the most of user's network connection and prevent downloading same data over and over again.